# SAS - substr is deleting from the end, I need from the start

Tags: sas

I have column with following Observations:

```
SSD
C2ES
M1 SSD
M1 C2ES
```

I want my final output like

```
SSD
C2ES
SSD
C2ES
```

I used the following code:

```
data dataset;
set dataset;
if substr(filiere,1,3) = 'M1 ' then filiere = substr(filiere,1,3);
run;
```

It removes 3 symbols from the end, what should I change in order to make it in right direction and if space is counted?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what your final output should look like ? do you want to remove the space or is it something else

Comment: @Kiran thanks for your response. 
It gives:
SSD
C2ES
M1
M1,

but I need only
SSD

C2ES

I want M1 SSD to become SSD and M1 C2ES to C2ES

Comment: SSD

C2ES

M1 SSD

M1 C2ES to become SSD, C2ES, SSD, C2ES

Answer (score 4):

You can something like below using Scan

```
data have;
input fielere & $20.;
datalines;
SSD
C2ES
M1 SSD
M1 C2ES
;

data want;
set have;
fielere = scan(fielere, -1);
run;
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you want this line

```
if substr(filiere,1,3) = 'M1 ' then filiere = substr(filiere,1,3);
```

to be this

```
if substr(filiere,1,3) = 'M1 ' then filiere = substr(filiere,4);
```